# I need an api that provides online voice recording

Tags: php, api, upload, voice

What is the best way to provide online voice recording in my website that would let the user record their voice directly from the browser and upload it to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This resource looks to have a lot of answers to the questions you will be asking.

**http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/feature-suggestions/10085/record-video-and-audio-via-a-live-webcam#msg86077**

From what I have seen, there is not yet proper browser support for recording sound, and as such the Flash way is the only way.  You need to set up a media server ([red5](http://code.google.com/p/red5/) is an open source version, there is also an [adobe version](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/)) and then provide a flash interface to it.

Apparently Flash 10.1 will allow recording without the need for a server.  Please read here: http://fms.denniehoopingarner.com/

Answer (score 1):

How about using flash actionscript ?

[Microphone Object](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary482.html)